# How to prevent selenium (Chrome) from overwriting existing downloaded file - Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I'm automating to download a file through selenium.
When I click this download button through selenium, it will automatically download the excel file.
No prompt will open, and the default file name is P3MLF.xls or P3MLF(xx).xls, xx = number depending on the last file downloaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMOjI.png)

I have no issue when running the script in normal mode (not headless).
But when in headless mode, downloaded file name is always P3MLF.xls and overwrites the existing P3MLF.xls file without adding a new file P3MLF(xx).xls.

How can I prevent to overwrite the existing file and download as normal in headless mode.

Here is my code I found to be able to download in headless mode:

```
  def download(self):
    self.opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    self.opt.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
    self.opt.add_argument('headless')
    self.opt.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    self.opt.add_argument('disable-gpu')
    self.opt.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
    self.ser = Service('SupportingFiles\chromedriver.exe')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.opt, service=self.ser)
    self.prefs = {
        'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        'download.default_directory': 'C:\\Drive_D\\Download', #this part actually not wowking
        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
        'download.directory_upgrade': True
        }
    self.opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", self.prefs)
    self.driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath':  self.dlPath_box.get()}}
    self.driver.execute('send_command', params)
```